# React native suddenly cannot build the ios version anymore

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm not sure if this is a bug. But suddenly I cannot build the IOS app anymore for debugging.

Running this command react-native run-ios as I have done many times before started producing this error: zerror Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening devvie.xcworkspace.z

I tried the suggestion and built the app with Xcode.app. I get this error: `library not found for -lDoubleConversion` I'm not sure what to do about that.

I also tried:

- Open Xcode project -> project settings -> Build system to Legacy Build System.
- Removing the ios/build folder.
- Update Xcode and react-native to the latest version (they were latest already)
- Run pod install from the ios directory.

The problem still persists and I don't know where to go from here. Hopefully, someone knows what's going on.

*This is the result from `react-native info`*

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.14.6
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
    Memory: 23.47 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 8.10.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.17.3 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.10.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 12.4, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.4, watchOS 5.3
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 29
      Build Tools: 29.0.2
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312
    Xcode: 10.3/10G8 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6
    react-native: 0.60.5 => 0.60.5
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Comment: Can you try opening Xcode-> folder icon in top left -> Press on your projectName icon -> make sure you are into the "general tab" -> go to the bottom  where it says "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" -> Click the plus (+) button -> search and add lDoubleConversion

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It finds two folders, but I cannot select either of them. The folders are: iOS 12.4 and Developer Frameworks.